# What to consider when manually removing a MSI installation?

Tags: .net-framework, windows, windows-installer

I'm dealing with a failing uninstall/upgrade of a very old MSI installation. So my intention was to manually remove the old installation by some kind of removal tool, preferable written in dotnet.

Is there anything to consider beside removing registry entries from 'HKLM\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall' and application files?

Comment: The Windows Installer (MSI) Cleanup utility (MSICUU2.exe) is [no longer recommended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651) by Microsoft. Instead they recommend the [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall). MSICUU2.exe is still available [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/MSI-cleanup-utility-3889c8db) if you're feeling especially adventurous.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the MSI foot print completely from the system, you would need to delete following from the system.

1. Product entry from the below hives - 
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products-Product Code GUID in cryptic format-.
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Components-Product Code GUID in cryptic format-.
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Patches-Product Code GUID in cryptic format-.
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products-Product Code GUID in cryptic format-.
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components-Product Code GUID in cryptic format-.
   SID - S-1-5-18 is for machine, you may need to go to the user specific SID if installation was done for a particular user.
2. Cached MSI from C:\windows\installer.

   - Uninstall reg key which you have mentioned. I think this should be the trace which should need to be cleaned up.